# What's the best place to early load dependencies in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I've written a couple of Controllers that implement an interface, so it has to be loaded before the Controller is loaded.  What's the standard place to early load dependencies in Codeigniter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add a [`require_once`](http://ca.php.net/require_once) at the top of the controller that loads the interface. You can't use the default CodeIgniter autoload as it doesn't support interfaces. While you could add the `require_once` lines at the top of `./config/autoload.php`, I would suggest adding it in each controller as follows:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

require_once APPPATH . 'controllers/Interface.php';

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {
  // Do something useful.
}
```

Comment: Okay, since there are no more people answering I guess this is the best solution.  Wow, once again Codeigniter really helped me out.

Comment: You could always just include it in your index.php file in htdocs

Answer (score 0):

In the autoload file: /config/autoload.php

Comment: Thank you but I've already tried that: autoload gets loaded after the controller.